# Editing the Answer appearing on another sites

Tags: support, edits, copycat-sites

I have answered one question on stack overflow. After some days, I have edited that answer, but the same question and answer available in an another [site](http://q2a.science/), with old answer, can we delete or modify the answer available on another site ?

Answer (score 3):

Some sites scrape Stack Overflow content and use it themselves. With proper attribution this is fine, but there may be a delay in updates appearing on these other sites, or the updates may not appear at all. There's little that can be done by you or by Stack Exchange to force an update.

It's possible that there may be some mechanism on the third party site to update the content, but since you haven't identified the site in question we wouldn't know.

Comment: The site is http://q2a.science/

Comment: @S.Karthik As with the main site, always update your post with additional information, instead of providing clearly msissing info in a comment (you can of course ping the answerer that you updated your post in a comment)